# How to evaluate a lazy list once?

Tags: haskell

[I referred to this post](http://www.garrisonjensen.com/2015/05/13/haskell-programs-are-lies.html) to compute a function `nthPrimes` that takes 
a list of n and returns a list of nth prime:

```
import qualified Data.Set as PQ

main :: IO ()
main = print $ nthPrimes ns
  where
    ns = [1,3,10]

nthPrimes :: [Int] -> [Integer]
nthPrimes = map (primes !!)

primes :: [Integer]
primes = 2:sieve [3,5..]
  where
    sieve (x:xs) = x : sieve' xs (insertprime x xs PQ.empty)

    sieve' (x:xs) table
        | nextComposite == x = sieve' xs (adjust x table)
        | otherwise          = x : sieve' xs (insertprime x xs table)
      where
        (nextComposite,_) = PQ.findMin table

    adjust x table
        | n == x    = adjust x (PQ.insert (n', ns) newPQ)
        | otherwise = table
      where
        Just ((n, n':ns), newPQ) = PQ.minView table

    insertprime p xs = PQ.insert (p*p, map (*p) xs)
```

So, this will print `[3,7,31]`.

However, since the `primes` function is lazy, it will be evaluated again and again in each call to get an nth-prime, but actually, we could just evaluate all the primes once if we know the `n` has a Max limit, (for instance `1000`), because `primes` never changes, and computing `primes` is CPU and Memory heavy.

So the question is how to force the evaluation of `primes` for the first X elements so that all the pre-evaluated elements can be reused in functions that take from it?

I believe reusing the pre-evaluated elements will reduce the overall Memory usage, especially when `ns` is a long list, correct?

Comment: I believe GHC is able to recognise that list is constant and only evaluate it once, however I'm not an expert so I'll leave the answer to someone more competent

Comment: `primes` isn't a function; it's a list *constructed* by lazy functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @chepner notes in the comments, `primes` is a list, not a function.  The way Haskell works, the elements of the `primes` list are computed on an as-needed basis but once computed they are kept in memory and not recomputed over and over.

You can see this yourself by loading your module into GHCi:

```
> :l MyPrimes
> :set +s
> nthPrimes [100000]
[1299721]
(6.45 secs, 3,246,628,344 bytes)
> nthPrimes [100001]
[1299743]
(0.01 secs, 188,184 bytes)
>
```

Calculating the 100,000th prime takes about 6 seconds.  Once that's done, calculating the 100,001st prime takes only 0.01 seconds.

Comment: In other words, the list is memoised, no?

Comment: It's not memoised in the traditional sense, which is a caching of function arguments to function return values. If anything, it's more like in-lining, where a thunk gets replaced with the value the thunk evaluates to. Think `2:sieve [3,5..]` being replaced with `2:3:5:7:11:sieve [13,15..]`. The delayed call to `sieve` is gone (or rather, replaced with a different delayed call), not just memoized.